# Linebreak after section number in memoir toc?

Tags: table-of-contents, line-breaking, memoir

I'm trying to finish my thesis and have received a bunch of formatting corrections that I need  to do, one of which I'm beating myself senseless trying to figure out.  I have to make the chapter entries in the table of contents look like this:

CHAPTER I

GENERAL INTRODUCTION................................................. 1

I've been playing with the memoir manual and my source to try and make this work, but I can't seem to get it to put a line break in after the section number.  Here's the redefinitions that I've already done for other required corrections:

```
\renewcommand*{\cftchaptername}{CHAPTER\space}
\renewcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{%
  \l@chapapp{\uppercase{#1}}{#2}{\cftchaptername}}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont}
```

and here's what I've done to try and insert the line break:

```
\renewcommand*{\cftchapteraftersnum}{\linebreak}
```

I've tried variations here, like \newline and \protect\newline (because of other posts I've seen, though I don't really understand when 'protect' is necessary). If anyone has any thoughts on how I might accomplish this, I'd be really grateful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}

\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}~}
\addtolength\mylen{1.5em}
\renewcommand\cftchaptername{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}~}
\renewcommand\cftchapterleader{\cftdotfill{\cftsectiondotsep}}
\renewcommand\cftchapteraftersnumb{\\\hspace*{-\mylen}}
\renewcommand\cftchapterfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftchapterpagefont{\normalfont}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{GENERAL INTRODUCTION}

\end{document}
```

[image]